# Why does the semigroup commute with integration?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, semigroup-of-operators

I have a question about Theorem 7.4.2 in Evan's PDEs book. If $S(t)$ is a contraction semigroup on a Banach space $X$. He uses $$S(r)\int_0^t S(s)u\,ds = \int_0^t S(r+s)u\,ds$$ and I don't understand how $S(r)$ and integration commute. Could anyone explain why this is true?

Comment: It is a linear map, but it should be strongly continuous. No need for contractions.

Answer (score 4):

Because $S$ is continuous, the following vector limit exists as a Riemann integral:
$$
          \int_{0}^{t}S(s)u ds = \lim_{\|\mathscr{P}\|\rightarrow 0}\sum_{\mathscr{P}}S(s_j^{\star})u\Delta s_j.
$$
Because $S(r)$ is a bounded linear operator, then $S(r)$ is continous, which gives
$$
\begin{align}
S(r)\int_{0}^{t}S(s)uds & = 
     S(r)\left(\lim_{\|\mathscr{P}\|\rightarrow 0}\sum_{\mathscr{P}}S(s_j^{\star})u\Delta s_j\right) \\
 & =\lim_{\|\mathscr{P}\|\rightarrow 0}S(r)\sum_{\mathscr{P}}S(s_j^{\star})u\Delta s_j \\
 & =\lim_{\|\mathscr{P}\|\rightarrow 0}\sum_{\mathscr{P}}S(r)S(s_j^{\star})u\Delta s_j \\
 & =\lim_{\|\mathscr{P}\|\rightarrow 0}\sum_{\mathscr{P}}S(r+s_j^{\star})u\Delta s_j \\
 & = \int_{0}^{t}S(r+s)uds
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1):

This is a particular case of the following result due to Hille.

> **Theorem.** Let $A:D(A)\subseteq X\to Y$ be a linear closed operator and let $x : \Omega\to D(A)$. Then
>   $$\int_{\Omega} A x(\omega)\;d\mu(\omega)=A\int_{\Omega} x(\omega)\;d\mu(\omega)$$
>   whenever both sides of the above equality are well-defined.

*Proof:* see [Vrabie's  book](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=T3lC9r51FEYC&printsec=frontcover&dq=vrabie+semigroups&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiB6tvjrI_NAhVJ_R4KHUcPA-wQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=vrabie%20semigroups&f=false) (Theorem 1.2.2, page 8) or [Diestel's book](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=fEKZAwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=Diestel+vector+measure&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjr8PDCrY_NAhUC8x4KHYcZBQMQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=Diestel%20vector%20measure&f=false) (Theorem 6, page 47) or [Hille's book](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=gf2VAwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=hille+functional+analysis+semigroups&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjMoeWDro_NAhUCqR4KHbZCAqUQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=hille%20functional%20analysis%20semigroups&f=false) (Theorem 3.7.12, page 83).