# If $v$ and $w$ are the weak derivatives of $u\in L^p(I,X)$ in $L^q(I,Y)$ and $L^r(I,Z)$ respectively, then $v=w$ almost everywhere

Tags: functional-analysis, weak-derivatives

Let

- $\lambda$ denote the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R$
- $I\subseteq\mathbb R$ be an interval
- $X,Y$ be a $\mathbb R$-Banach space such that $X$ can be embedded into $Y$
- $1\le p,q\le\infty$
- $u\in L^p(I,X)$

We say that $u$ has a weak derivative in $L^q(I,Y)$ $:\Leftrightarrow$ $\exists v\in L^q(I,Y)$ with $$\int_I\varphi'u\;{\rm d}\lambda=-\int_I\varphi v\:{\rm d}\lambda\;\;\;\text{for all }\varphi\in C_c^\infty(I)\tag 1\;.$$ In that case, we write $$\frac{{\rm d}u}{{\rm d}t}=v\tag 2\;.$$

> The question is: Does the notation introduced in $(2)$ makes sense?

To be precise: I've read that we can prove the following: Let $Z$ be another $\mathbb R$-Banach space such that $Y$ is densely embedded into $Z$ and such that $Z'$ is separable (which condition on $Z$ would imply the seperability of $Z'$?). Moreover, let $1\le r\le\infty$ and $w$ be the weak derivative of $u$ in $L^r(I,Z)$. Then $v=w$ $\lambda$-almost surely.

> How can we prove this statement?

Answer (score 1):

To prove the statement note that if 
$$\int_I v\varphi=\int_I w\varphi\tag{A}$$ for all $\varphi\in C_c^\infty$, then $v=w$ a.e. by the Du Bois Reymond Lemma. Note that the density of the embedding $Y\subset Z$ and the separability of $Z'$ were not used.

With respect to the other question: if $Z$ is separable and reflexive, then $Z'$ is separable (and reflexive). If $Z$ is separable but not reflexive, then $Z'$ can be not separable ($Z=\ell^1$ is an example).

---

### Edit.

The above argument works if the embedding $\iota$ from $X$ to $Y$ and the embedding $\kappa$ from $Y$ to $Z$ are linear and continuous. In this case, the precise meaning of $(A)$ is
$$\int_I \kappa(v)\varphi=\int_I w\varphi\tag{A}$$ 
and the precise conclusion is $\kappa(v)=w$ a.e. However this is not the case that the OP have in mind (see the comments below).

Comment: (a) I've still got some problems to understand how we need to read the definition given in the question. Let $ι$ denote the embedding of $X$ into $Y$ and $κ$ denote the embedding of $Y$ into $Z$. Then, if $v$ is a weak derivative of $u$, we should have $$ι\left(\int_Iφ'u\:{\rm d}λ\right)=-\int_Iφ v\:{\rm d}λ\tag 3\;.$$ Unless $ι$ is linear, we don't have $ι\left(\int_Iφ'u\:{\rm d}λ\right)=\int_Iφ'ι(u)\:{\rm d}λ$. Do you agree until this point?

Comment: (b) Now, your equation should read $$κ\left(\int_Ivφ\:{\rm d}λ\right)=\int_Iφ w\:{\rm d}λ\tag 4\;.$$ Can we really apply the *du Bois Reymond Lemma* to conclude that $κ(v)=w$ a.e. (having in mind that $κ\left(\int_Ivφ\:{\rm d}λ\right)\ne\int_Iv\kappa(\varphi)\:{\rm d}\lambda$)?

Comment: @0xbadf00d I'm sorry, I had continuous embedding in mind. I will think in your questions.

Comment: What do you say to the rest of my comments?

Comment: @0xbadf00d (a) In the question, "$X$ can be embedded into $Y$" and "$Y$ is densely embedded into $Z$". *Usually* (maybe *always* because I've never seen a different meaning in this context) this means that there exist an injective linear map $\iota$ from $X$ to $Y$ and an injective linear map $\kappa$ from $Y$ to $Z$ such that $\overline{\kappa(Y)}=Z$. Intuitively, this means that $X$ can be viewed as a subspace of $Y$ and $Y$ can be viewed as a dense subspace of $Z$. If it is not the case, please clarify the meaning of *embedded*.

Comment: @0xbadf00d Even in this case (linear and injective), I think we cannot [commute $\iota$ with $\int$](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1812820/70305). Linearity is not enough and closedness is necessary. So, "Unless $\iota$ is linear" should be replaced by "Unless $\iota$ is linear and closed, and $\iota\circ u\in L^1_{\text{loc}}(I)$". Of course, if the embending is continuous (which happens in a lot of important cases) these requirements are fulfilled.

Comment: When I say "$X$ is embedded into $Y$", I mean that there is an injective, continuous and open (as a mapping onto $\iota(X)$) function $\iota:X\to Y$, i.e. $\iota$ is a [homeomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeomorphism#Definition) onto $\iota(X)$.

Comment: I know that "$L(\int f)=\int L(f)$" for a bounded linear operator $L$ (and I can imagine that it's also true for closed linear operators). That's why I said "Unless $\iota$ is linear" above (since then $\iota$ is a bounded linear operator). I'm not sure, if I really understood your last comment. Do you think that "$\iota$ commutes with $\int$" for the $\iota$ of my last comment?

Comment: @0xbadf00d In my sentence "if the embedding is continuous then these requirements are fulfilled" the word "embedding" means "a linear injective map", as in my prior comment. But you have clarified that you are considering other meaning (I've considered a  structure-preserving map between normed spaces (in which case the linearity is given) and you have considered a  structure-preserving map between topological spaces). So, no. I did not say that $\iota$ commutes with $\int$ in your case. Where you have read the statement you want to prove?

Comment: I've read it in [Remark II.5.1](https://books.google.de/books?id=ZYAW5D8xI1MC&pg=PA95&lpg=PA95&dq=%22Remark+II.5.1%22+%22boyer%22&source=bl&ots=QaRYlQ0zjE&sig=5jJ-EC4xEhC2Lu7q_LPRmB90KlI&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjM1IPLz5zRAhVlGsAKHbiUD5gQ6AEIHDAA) (I hope you have access to it from your region) of *Mathematical Tools for the Study of the Incompressible Navier-Stokes Equations and Related Models* by *Franck Boyer* and *Pierre Fabrie*.

Comment: You didn't said it explicitly, but I guess you agree to me that we cannot apply the *du Bois Reymond Lemma*, if $\iota$ doesn't commute with $\int$ and hence that's the crucial point, right?

Comment: @0xbadf00d With respect to (b), yes, you are right. I agree with you.

Comment: Are you sure that $\iota$ needs to be a bounded linear operator, too? If $\iota:X\to Y$ and $\kappa:Y\to Z$ are embeddings (in the sense of my definition), then $\kappa\circ\iota$ is an embedding from $X\to Z$. Thus, it makes at least sense to talk about a weak derivative $w$ of $u$ in $L^r_{\text{loc}}(I,Z)$ for some $r\in[1,\infty]$. Now, in order for $$\int_I\phi w=-\int_I\phi'(\kappa\circ\iota)u=-\kappa\int_I\phi'\iota u=\kappa\int_I\phi v=\int_I\phi\kappa v$$ for all $\phi\in C_c^\infty(I)$ to hold, we should only need that $\kappa$ is a bounded linear operator.

Comment: And let me add another question: If we use your definition of an embedding, then $ι$ is an injective linear function. You said your claim will hold, if this $ι$ is "closed". But what did you mean by closedness in this scenario? Usually, a linear operator $(\mathcal D(A),A)$ on a Banach space $E$ is called **closed**, if $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq\mathcal D(A)$ with $x_n→x$ for some $x∈E$ and $Ax_n→y$ for some $y∈E$ implies $x\in\mathcal D(A)$ and $y=Ax$. For $ι$, this definition doesn't make much sense, since it should simply mean that $ι$ is even continuous. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Moreover, you've said "I've considered a structure-preserving map between normed spaces [...] and you have considered a structure-preserving map between topological spaces". I guess you've meant that you've considered a structure preserving map between **vector spaces** (i.e. a linear map), didn't you? Injectivity and linearity are properties which don't depend on the topology of the corresponding (vector) spaces.